# Get the length of the array if the specific key is not equal to null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state with an array of objects:

```
const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([
  { url: null, name: null},
  { url: 'anyURL', name: null},
  { url: null, name: null}
]);
```

I want to get the length of this array if the key `url` is not null.

I do it like this:

```
const UploadedLogosWithURL = UploadLogos.map((logo) => {
  return logo.url !== null;
})

<button onClick={() => { console.log(UploadedLogosWithURL.length) }}>
  Click
</button>
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `array.map(...).length` is always `array.length` (nothing to do with React, that's just basic JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kanishk6103 got it right. Although, I would like to make it more short by simply returning the URL key ( it will check if its not null )

```
const [UploadLogos, setUploadLogos] = useState([
  { url: null, name: null},
  { url: 'anyURL', name: null},
  { url: null, name: null}
]);
```

```
<button 
   onClick={() => { 
      console.log(UploadLogos.filter((logo) => logo.url)).length) 
   }}
>
  Click
</button>
```

This should also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use filter()? it would be something like:

`const newArray = UploadLogos.filter(item => item.url !== null);`

`<button onClick={() => { console.log(newArray.length) }}> Click </button>` 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your state, then get the length of your filtered array.

```js
const initialLogos = [
  { url: null, name: null},
  { url: 'anyURL', name: null},
  { url: null, name: null}
]

const [logos, setLogos] = useState(initialLogos)

const logosWithUrl = logos.filter(logo => logo.url !== null);
const logosWithUrlLength = logosWithUrl.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works just fine, the problem is the use of `.map()`, what's happening is that you're creating a new array, populated with the boolean results of whether or not `logo.url !== null`
i.e. `[false, true, false]`

from MDN:

> The map() method of Array instances creates a new array populated with
> the results of calling a provided function on every element in the
> calling array.

The solution of @kanishk6103 would solve it, but a small enhancement is that you don't have to use the comparison because you're checking for booleans,
so a more concise way would be:

```
UploadLogos.filter(logo => logo.url);
```